# Find $(\overrightarrow{a}\times\overrightarrow{b})\cdot \overrightarrow{c}$

Tags: vector-spaces, vectors, vector-analysis

$\overrightarrow{a},\overrightarrow{b},$ and $\overrightarrow{c}$ be 3 non coplanar unit vector such that angle between every pair of them is $\frac{\pi}{3}$.

Find $(\overrightarrow{a}\times\overrightarrow{b})\cdot \overrightarrow{c}$

**Approach:**

$(\overrightarrow{a}\times\overrightarrow{b})\cdot \overrightarrow{c}=(|\overrightarrow{a}||\overrightarrow{b}|\sin{\theta})(\hat{n}\cdot \overrightarrow{c})$

$\implies |\overrightarrow{a}||\overrightarrow{b}| |\overrightarrow{c}|\sin{\theta} \cos(\alpha)$.

**Doubt:** How to find angle between unit vector $\hat{n}$ and $\overrightarrow{c}$ which is $\alpha$ .

**I know other method to solve this question but i want to approach using this method only.**

I check for duplicate. I didn't find any question having same doubt as me.

Comment: see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triple_product.

Comment: Are you not complicating this? If you have to solve through vectors, why apply trigonometry? Even if you are particularly interested in finding the angle that you are talking about, the vector dot product gives you that.

Comment: and $\cos \alpha$ is $\sqrt{\frac{2}{3}}$.

Comment: how did you calculate $cos\alpha=(\sqrt(2/3))$ with dot product. Can you elaborate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Construct a tetrahedron with vectors at a vertex of base (say $P$), being: $\mathbf {a,b,c}$. Let the base of this tetrahedron have vectors $\mathbf {a,b}$, and let the base be placed parallel to the ground. Then, we wish to find angle between $\mathbf c$ and the vertical ($\alpha$). This angle would be equal to $90°-$(Angle between base and $\mathbf c$). Now, drop a perpendicular from the top of the tetrahedron (say $O$), let it meet base at $Q$, and use elementary trigonometry for right triangle $OQP$ to find out the angle between $\mathbf c$ and base.

Comment: I know how to do it but i am not getting it. In fact I've solved the problem using determinant method. But not able to find angle $\alpha$ using this method.

Comment: I did not tell you about the determinant method. I know you are not looking for that. So I told you how to find $\alpha $.

Comment: yes, bro. I've already thought whatever you suggested that's why i took help of stack exchange. When i take projection of $\overrightarrow{c}$ on  base of $\overrightarrow{b},\overrightarrow{a}$ I've only hypotenuse that is $|\overrightarrow{C}|$. I don''t have one more parameter. It's being difficult for me to visualize.

Comment: No, you also know the length of base of triangle OPQ, because you know that Q would be the centroid of base which is an equilateral triangle.

Comment: thanks understood. $Q$ will be centroid. I was missing that.

Answer (score 0):

$\hat{n}$ perpendicular to the plane span by $\vec{a}$ and $\vec{b}$
angle between plane and $\vec{c}$ is as $\pi/3$, thus $\alpha = \pi/6$

Comment: bro, your answer is wrong.  You have to check answer provided by Ritem.